# Using Constants to initialize a swift array

Tags: arrays, swift, constants

I have a 2 dimensional array that I am trying to use to map a set of values from pickers to a specific set of values.  I want to make it readable so I tried to use the C style and defined my set of values as constants and then used them in the initialization, however I'm getting an error telling me that my class does not have a member named the constant.  I tested it in the playground and everything worked which makes sense since the playground is interpretive.  Anyone have any ideas how best to address this.  I know how to solve the problem from a technical perspective but am obsessive about maintaining readability.  Below is the code sipper

```
// definitions for FORCE objects

let LIVELY              = 0
let LIGHT               = 1
let ROUNDED             = 2
let POWERFUL            = 3
let CHAMPAGNE           = 4
let SUCREBLANC          = 5
let SUCREROUGEOUBLANC   = 6
let SUCREROUGE          = 7
let CHAMPAGNEROSE       = 8
let ROSE                = 9

//definitions for SAVEUR objects

let FLORAL              = 0
let FRUITY              = 1
let OAKY                = 2
let SPICY               = 3

let redForceNamePointerArray = [
    /*           1     2        3       4      5        6            7             8         9       10      11         12    */
    /* 1 */   [LIGHT,ROUNDED,POWERFUL,NOIMAGE,LIGHT,CHAMPAGNE,SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,CHAMPAGNE,ROUNDED,ROUNDED,SUCREBLANC,POWERFUL],
    /* 1 */   [LIGHT,ROUNDED,POWERFUL,NOIMAGE,LIGHT,CHAMPAGNE,SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,CHAMPAGNE,ROUNDED,ROUNDED,SUCREBLANC,POWERFUL],
    /* 1 */   [LIGHT,ROUNDED,POWERFUL,NOIMAGE,LIGHT,CHAMPAGNE,SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,CHAMPAGNE,ROUNDED,ROUNDED,SUCREBLANC,POWERFUL],
    /* 1 */   [LIGHT,ROUNDED,POWERFUL,NOIMAGE,LIGHT,CHAMPAGNE,SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,CHAMPAGNE,ROUNDED,ROUNDED,SUCREBLANC,POWERFUL],
    /* 1 */   [LIGHT,ROUNDED,POWERFUL,NOIMAGE,LIGHT,CHAMPAGNE,SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,CHAMPAGNE,ROUNDED,ROUNDED,SUCREBLANC,POWERFUL],
    /* 1 */   [LIGHT,ROUNDED,POWERFUL,NOIMAGE,LIGHT,CHAMPAGNE,SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,CHAMPAGNE,ROUNDED,ROUNDED,SUCREBLANC,POWERFUL]];

l
```

Comment: Yeah so you have an extraneous 1 at the end.  Maybe a SO typo or could be your problem.

Comment: extra l, also there is no constant named NOIMAGE

Answer (score 2):

Constant initializers can't refer to other constants in the class.  It's a limitation of the language or the compiler.  Here's an alternative:

```
class C {
    enum Image: Int {
        case NOIMAGE = -1
        case LIVELY
        case LIGHT
        case ROUNDED
        case POWERFUL
        case CHAMPAGNE
        case SUCREBLANC
        case SUCREROUGEOUBLANC
        case SUCREROUGE
        case CHAMPAGNEROSE
        case ROSE
    }

    enum Flavor: Int {
        case FLORAL = 0
        case FRUITY
        case OAKY
        case SPICY
    }

    let redForceNamePointerArray: [[Image]] = {
        typealias I = Image
        return [
            /*           1     2        3       4      5        6            7             8         9       10      11         12    */
            /* 1 */   [I.LIGHT,I.ROUNDED,I.POWERFUL,I.NOIMAGE,I.LIGHT,I.CHAMPAGNE,I.SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,I.CHAMPAGNE,I.ROUNDED,I.ROUNDED,I.SUCREBLANC,I.POWERFUL],
            /* 1 */   [I.LIGHT,I.ROUNDED,I.POWERFUL,I.NOIMAGE,I.LIGHT,I.CHAMPAGNE,I.SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,I.CHAMPAGNE,I.ROUNDED,I.ROUNDED,I.SUCREBLANC,I.POWERFUL]
        ]
    }()
}
```

But now `redForceNamePointerArray`'s elements are `C.Image` instead of `Int`.  If you really want them to be `Int`:

```
    let redForceNamesInt: [[Int]] = {
        typealias I = Image
        return [
            /*           1     2        3       4      5        6            7             8         9       10      11         12    */
            /* 1 */   [I.LIGHT,I.ROUNDED,I.POWERFUL,I.NOIMAGE,I.LIGHT,I.CHAMPAGNE,I.SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,I.CHAMPAGNE,I.ROUNDED,I.ROUNDED,I.SUCREBLANC,I.POWERFUL],
            /* 1 */   [I.LIGHT,I.ROUNDED,I.POWERFUL,I.NOIMAGE,I.LIGHT,I.CHAMPAGNE,I.SUCREROUGEOUBLANC,I.CHAMPAGNE,I.ROUNDED,I.ROUNDED,I.SUCREBLANC,I.POWERFUL]
        ].map { $0.map { $0.rawValue } }
    }()
```

Comment: Thanks Rob the enum approach will work! there is no need to have integers